# Full screen overlay menu scrollable

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, overlay, disable

I am working on an overlay menu. I am working on an overlay menu. How can I disable scrolling when overlay is open?

I tried doing `overflow:'auto' in body tag and it worked but few of my sections were not getting displayed. I am not able to figure out the jQuery for the same. Please suggest a suitable solution.

```js
$('#toggle').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('#overlay').toggleClass('open');
});

$(".fulloverlay a").on("click", function() {
  $('#toggle').toggleClass('active');
  $('#overlay').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.container p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.container a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FF5252;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 5px;
}
.container a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #FF5252;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 0.35s ease;
}
.container a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', sans-serif;
}

.button_container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  right: 2%;
  height: 27px;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
}
.button_container:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.button_container.active .top {
  transform: translateY(10px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
  background: #FFF;
}
.button_container.active .middle {
  opacity: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}
.button_container.active .bottom {
  transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
  background: #FFF;
}
.button_container span {
  background: #FF5252;
  border: none;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button_container span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 10px;
}
.button_container span:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 20px;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, visibility 0.35s, width 0.35s;
  z-index: 50;
}
.overlay:before {
  content: '';
  background: #FF5252;
  left: -55%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: left 0.35s ease;
}
.overlay:after {
  content: '';
  background: #FF5252;
  right: -55%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}
.overlay.open {
  opacity: 0.9;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
}
.overlay.open:before {
  left: 0;
}
.overlay.open:after {
  right: 0;
}
.overlay.open li {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInRight 0.5s ease forwards;
          animation: fadeInRight 0.5s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.35s;
          animation-delay: 0.35s;
}
.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.45s;
          animation-delay: 0.45s;
}
.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.55s;
          animation-delay: 0.55s;
}
.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.65s;
          animation-delay: 0.65s;
}
.overlay nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
}
.overlay ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.overlay ul li {
  display: block;
  height: 25%;
  height: calc(100% / 4);
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overlay ul li a:hover:after, .overlay ul li a:focus:after, .overlay ul li a:active:after {
  width: 100%;
}
.overlay ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 3px;
  background: #FFF;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body translate='no' >
  <div class='container'>
  <h1>Top right corner, click it!</h1>
</div>

<div class='button_container' id='toggle'>
  <span class='top'></span>
  <span class='middle'></span>
  <span class='bottom'></span>
</div>

<div class='overlay' id='overlay'>
  <nav class='overlay-menu' id="fulloverlay">
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#about2' >Home</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Work</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<section class="about" id="about" style="background-color: white; height: 100vh;"></section>
<section class="about2" id="about2" style="background-color:aqua; height: 100vh;"></section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to use `overflow: hidden`, not `overflow: auto`, on the `body`.

Also note the JS can be made more succinct by joining the event handlers together in a single function call, as you're effectively performing the same logic in both of them. Try this:

```js
let toggleOverlay = () => {
  $('#toggle').toggleClass('active');
  $('#overlay').toggleClass('open');  
  $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
}

$("#toggle, .fulloverlay a").on("click", toggleOverlay);
```

```css
body.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.container a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FF5252;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 5px;
}

.container a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #FF5252;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 0.35s ease;
}

.container a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', sans-serif;
}

.button_container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  right: 2%;
  height: 27px;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
}

.button_container:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.button_container.active .top {
  transform: translateY(10px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
  background: #FFF;
}

.button_container.active .middle {
  opacity: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}

.button_container.active .bottom {
  transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
  background: #FFF;
}

.button_container span {
  background: #FF5252;
  border: none;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button_container span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 10px;
}

.button_container span:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 20px;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, visibility 0.35s, width 0.35s;
  z-index: 50;
}

.overlay:before {
  content: '';
  background: #FF5252;
  left: -55%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: left 0.35s ease;
}

.overlay:after {
  content: '';
  background: #FF5252;
  right: -55%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

.overlay.open {
  opacity: 0.9;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay.open:before {
  left: 0;
}

.overlay.open:after {
  right: 0;
}

.overlay.open li {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInRight 0.5s ease forwards;
  animation: fadeInRight 0.5s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.35s;
  animation-delay: 0.35s;
}

.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.45s;
  animation-delay: 0.45s;
}

.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.55s;
  animation-delay: 0.55s;
}

.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.65s;
  animation-delay: 0.65s;
}

.overlay nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
}

.overlay ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay ul li {
  display: block;
  height: 25%;
  height: calc(100% / 4);
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay ul li a:hover:after,
.overlay ul li a:focus:after,
.overlay ul li a:active:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 3px;
  background: #FFF;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='container'>
  <h1>Top right corner, click it!</h1>
</div>

<div class='button_container' id='toggle'>
  <span class='top'></span>
  <span class='middle'></span>
  <span class='bottom'></span>
</div>

<div class='overlay' id='overlay'>
  <nav class='overlay-menu' id="fulloverlay">
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#about2'>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Work</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<section class="about" id="about" style="background-color: white; height: 100vh;"></section>
<section class="about2" id="about2" style="background-color:aqua; height: 100vh;"></section>
```